# Why is font-family "Arial" larger then "Times" on desktop, and "Times New Roman" is larger then "Arial" on mobile?

Tags: android, html, css, fonts

On my desktop page, the Font-Family: Arial; is larger than Font-Family: Times New Roman; with both of their font-size:50px;

However, on my mobile device, the "Times" font appears larger than the "Arial". Is there a simple way for me to correct this so that the android view is the same proportion as the desktop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different fonts have different "aspect values" which is the size difference between a lowercase x and uppercase X for instance. You could try to use something like "font-size adjust" in your css to make all fonts have the same aspect value regardless of the font family.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old post but try

```
-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;
-ms-text-size-adjust:none;
-moz-text-size-adjust:none;
text-size-adjust:none;
```